# How can I use a trumpet in a pop rock band?

Tags: trumpet, brass, band, instrumentation

We need to arrange several **pop rock songs**. The band has vocals, acoustic guitar, electric guitar, bass, drums and keyboards. In addition, we add **a trumpet**. Do you have any idea, method or example of how to play the songs with the trumpet?

Comment: There are few if any pop rock songs which can directly use a trumpet, i think you would have to make an arrangement specifically for your trumpet

Comment: Being a cornetist, I've always wondered this also. I play the violin part in some Skillet songs with my cornet, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: sorry i don't have a good answer to this. if it were me i'd be tempted to just get everyone together and send a couple of hours jamming it out, and move forward based on how well it seemed to 'gel'

Comment: Are you familiar with these rock bands that featured trumpet? Look them up. Chicago. Blood, Sweat and Tears. Cake. Sly and the Family Stone. The Who (on the album "Quadrophenia"). Fleming & John. Sun-60. Some "fusion" work by Miles Davis. Also reference Chuck Mangione (that was fluegelhorn, actually).

Comment: Also lots of funk bands. Kool and the Gang. Earth, Wind and Fire. The Commodores.

Comment: As Wheat said, listen to some Cake. Also lots of Super Furry Animals songs use trumpet well.

Comment: See how others do it so you have some context.  For example, I Will Survive by the band Cake.

Comment: Typically, a single wind or brass instrument would get solos. Perhaps you can, in some cases, re-inforce part of a guitar riff, however, you'll risk sounding like a deficient horn backing section. If the band is serious about adding wind/brass, you should consider getting either or both a (tenor) sax and trombone. This will allow you to make more background arrangements, and the arrangements can continue even when one brass has a solo.

Comment: And also, do your own thing.  Ian Anderson was told by pretty much everyone that there was no place for a flute in a rock band, so he took the outrageously outre step of creating one himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose with a cornet you'll have the ability to add something extra in for texture, so something like finding the main melody line in the song, whether it be with guitar or vocals have the trumpet follow this line to emphasise the line and it could offer a massive difference to the sound and feel of the song depending, you should try looking at reel big fish, they get away with a trumpet

Answer (score 2):

I think the answers so far spend too few consideration on the fact that we're talking here about a *single* trumpet added to a standard rock ensemble. Sure, there is lots of pop/rock music with brass and wind, but that is actually quite different from only having a single trumpet.

Typically, a single wind or brass instrument would only be truly capable of some solos. In some cases you might be able to mimick a full horn section and re-inforce part of a guitar riff. However, with a single trumpet, it is going to sound very thin, and you'll risk sounding like the rest of the horn backing section is on sick leave.

If the band is serious about adding wind/brass, you should consider getting either or both a (tenor) sax and trombone. This will allow you to make more background arrangements, and the arrangements can continue even when one brass has a solo. If that is not an option, I fear the trumpet will be confined to playing an intro or a solo here and there, maybe a couple of accents on a hook.

Comment: Louis Armstrong?

Comment: @BobRodes You mean, because Armstrong has this enormous track record playing a single trumpet in pop-rock bands? :p

Comment: Nope. I mean that styles don't define musicians, musicians define styles.  Ask any music executive.

Comment: @BobRodes Ok. But in defining this style, there is a concrete challenge to somehow make the single trumpet not sound too thin when in a backing role. Or, as I pointed out, be satisfied to give the trumpet only solos. I'm certainly not an expert re Armstrong, but a lot of the stuff I heard from him, the trumpet is either solo in a very small jazz ensemble, or it is a jazz ensemble with a horn section. It's probably ignorance on my part, but I don't see how he could be an example for this particular question.

Comment: I also think that there is a big difference between how a brass section and a single trumpet is applied, and that the answers focusing on the former are not so useful concerning this particular question.

Comment: @RolandBouman fair enough, if you are talking about arranging existing music, which this question is indeed asking.  By the way, when I say "ask any music executive" I mean to say that whatever a music executive says is true is evidence for the opposite case.  :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some good examples. Have a look at Less Than Jake's song,  Gainesville Rock City:

You need to arrange the songs so it works, but rock music can definitely cope with non-standard instruments.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples of bands with horns (including trumpets). Going back a few decades two of the most prominent would be "Blood Sweat and Tears" and "Chicago." There's also the 70's band "Tower of Power." How about the Beatles ("All you Need Is Love")? The one-hit-wonder band "Alive and Kicking" with "Tighter, Tighter."

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First question is what do you want the horns to do? Just back up the band--as in a a typical horn section?

If this is the case, the horns typically add support to the chord changes--so, you could try having the horn notes mirror the root and harmony notes of the individual chords. Many many R&B tunes are based on a I-IV-V progression--and the horns support as indicated (harmonizing against the chord changes)--and for the refrain, they typically walk down in a V-IV-Flat III-Root sequence (not necessarily single whole tones down.

If you want the horns to carry melodies, that is an entirely different question, and I think whether a horn would sound good doing that really depends on the piece--a lot of music sounds good w/ backing horns, but not necessarily w/ horns carrying the melody--just my 2 cents

Answer (score 1):

Put it through some effects, like an octave lower-er or something that makes the sound very reverberaty / echoey.  That way you can add ambience or texture without distracting from the rest of the composition and layers.

Check out the band Cake, they do a great job adding horn skillfully without using any sort of effects.

Answer (score 1):

I have played trumpet for years, and am currently playing trumpet in a band. Trumpets have a wide range of styles they can do, so don't be afraid to experiment. Trumpets are very good for in the background or the occasional solo, but can do more than that as well, so it really depends on the song itself, and the player. If the trumpet player likes going fast and high, then its easy to give them solos and complex rhythms and that will sound fine. If they don't really like being in the spotlight, that's a bit harder because trumpet is a very attention-grabbing instrument but a quiet background is possible.